# Pandas: Split a single dataframe into multiple not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

The code I have is suppose to split a single dataframe into multiple.

I have a bool to make the split...

```
df['truth'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('System starting'), True, False)

for _, x in df.groupby((df['truth'] == True).cumsum()):
    print(x.reset_index(drop=False))
```

The fist split works fine:

```
                Time  error_id                                        Description Set Clear  error_type  truth
0  2023-04-25 06:01:16.100       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9     CLEAR           2  False
1  2023-04-25 06:01:27.150       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9       SET           2  False
2  2023-04-25 06:02:53.650       474  Speed Reduction 989: Haulages at their Load Limit       SET           1  False
3  2023-04-25 06:02:54.100       474  Speed Reduction 989: Haulages at their Load Limit     CLEAR           1  False
4  2023-04-25 06:04:16.450       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9       SET           2  False
..                     ...       ...                                                ...       ...         ...    ...
89 2023-04-25 06:21:06.050       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9       SET           2  False
90 2023-04-25 06:21:39.650       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9       SET           2  False
91 2023-04-25 06:21:39.300       564  RH RA Gear Train  Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9     CLEAR           2  False
92 2023-04-25 06:22:35.626       732                  EIP Instance 170 Counter stopped.       SET           3  False
93 2023-04-25 06:22:35.626       767  EIP Instance 211 (Shield Collison Monitoring) ...     CLEAR           3  False

[94 rows x 6 columns]
```

Then I get:

```
                  Time  error_id                                        Description Set Clear  error_type  truth
0  2023-04-25 06:22:35.569       669                     System starting - Please wait.       SET           3   True
1  2023-04-25 06:22:35.569       732                  EIP Instance 170 Counter stopped.       SET           3  False
2  2023-04-25 06:22:35.569       767  EIP Instance 211 (Shield Collison Monitoring) ...       SET           3  False
3  2023-04-25 06:22:35.569       660   Data transmission to external PLC is interrupted       SET           2  False   ..........


                      Time  error_id                                        Description Set Clear  error_type  truth
0  2023-04-25 06:22:55.576       669                     System starting - Please wait.     CLEAR           3   True
1  2023-04-25 06:22:57.876       732                  EIP Instance 170 Counter stopped.       SET           3  False
2  2023-04-25 06:23:05.926       767  EIP Instance 211 (Shield Collison Monitoring) ...     CLEAR           3  False
3  2023-04-25 06:23:11.576       354               RH Methane Monitor Line Fault +4-B18       SET           3  False
```

If you did not pick it, there is no **[xx rows x 6 columns]** at the end of the 2nd dataframe (after idx 3) and the next (the 3rd).

At every True, there should be a new dataframe. It happens throughout the entire dataframe. Any ideas why this is occurring?

The dataset if required:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Antavf-wwI41j3f1vF05WecwkHR-?e=0wt0tB

**UPDATE**

A slight mod:

```
df_list = [(k, g) for k, g in df.groupby((df['truth'] == 
True).cumsum())]
print(df_list)
```

Where its not splitting correctly, get: A comma is after the last False, no DF

```
29326 2023-04-26 05:56:37.812       582   LH RA Planetary Gearbox: Oil Level too low +5-B6       SET           3  False), (40,                          Time  error_id                                        Description Set Clear  error_type  truth     
29327 2023-04-26 05:56:37.762       669                     System starting - Please wait.     CLEAR           3   True
29328 2023-04-26 05:56:42.562       582   LH RA Planetary Gearbox: Oil Level too low +5-B6     CLEAR           3  False
29329 2023-04-26 05:56:42.562       732                  EIP Instance 170 Counter stopped.     CLEAR           3  False
```

Comment: The later datasets only have 4 rows, so all rows are displayed by the print statement. There's no need to tell you how many total rows there are because you can see them all. (it's also obvious for the first group how many rows there are because of the index, but it might not have been if the index wasn't just a simple range index)

Comment: @ThePhoton,  you saying it’s an outcome of the print statement?

Comment: Please don't link to external data, include a meaningful short example directly in your question instead.

Comment: I can't replicate this _"there is no [xx rows x 6 columns] at the end of the 2nd dataframe (after idx 3) and the next (the 3rd)"_. Your 2. problem is due to how `print` is designed. (Side note: `df.groupby((df['truth'] ==  True).cumsum())` is the same as `df.groupby(df['truth'].cumsum())`.)

Comment: Thanks all, it must be the print statement.. albeit its odd for me that it prints some frames correctly and not others.  Ive not seen this print behavior before. always after every data frame  it prints xx rows and yy columns.  @Timus xx is just the row number at the end of a data frame.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but still: When I tried it on a sample of your data it did show those infos for all sub-dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) and turn on `show_dimensions` :

```
for _, g in df.groupby(df["error_id"]):
    print(g.to_string(show_dimensions=True))
```

Output :

```
                      Time  error_id                              Description Set Clear error_type  truth
2  2023-04-25 06:02:53.650       474  Speed Reduction 989: Haulages at their Load Limit        SET      1
3  2023-04-25 06:02:54.100       474  Speed Reduction 989: Haulages at their Load Limit      CLEAR      1

[2 rows x 5 columns]
                      Time  error_id                             Description Set Clear error_type  truth
0  2023-04-25 06:01:16.100       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9      CLEAR      2
1  2023-04-25 06:01:27.150       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9        SET      2
4  2023-04-25 06:04:16.450       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9        SET      2
5  2023-04-25 06:21:06.050       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9        SET      2
6  2023-04-25 06:21:39.650       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9        SET      2
7  2023-04-25 06:21:39.300       564  RH RA Gear Train Oil: Temperature too high +6-B9      CLEAR      2

[6 rows x 5 columns]
                      Time  error_id              Description Set Clear error_type  truth
8  2023-04-25 06:22:35.626       732  EIP Instance 170 Counter stopped.        SET      3

[1 rows x 5 columns]
                      Time  error_id                              Description Set Clear error_type  truth
9  2023-04-25 06:22:35.626       767  EIP Instance 211 (Shield Collison Monitoring) ...      CLEAR      3

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```